PostgreSQL unreadable/unknown error message
In terms of software development course I had to set up PostgreSQL on my laptop (Windows 11 x64). At pgAdmin on server creation (register) stage I reveived unreadable error message. I only managed myself is server name, host name, and password. Also if I change the username to some other it will placed instead of "postgres". Changing of pgAdmin interface language didn't helped. All the references are below
Also remind you that after I downloaded PostgreSQL (or pgAdmin) there is preset "PostgreSQL 16" server that has hostname=localhost and port=5432. If this server prevents me from creating a new one (with current settings), what do I need to change in the settings of the new server?




The implication here is that you do NOT have a Postgres server running on your machine.  Remember that pgAdmin does not automatically install a server.  That's completely separate.  Does your machine default to a language other than English?

Looks like you installed pgAdmin, not PostgreSQL. pgAdmin is just one of many SQL clients that can be used to connect to PostgreSQL.

@TimRoberts, Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. At the moment, I have russian language on my machine

@FrankHeikens, Thanks for your respond. I managed to go this way: Google search "download PostgreSQL" -> PostgreSQL official website -> Download -> Windows -> "Download the installer certified by EDB for all supported PostgreSQL versions." -> PostgreSQL version 16.3 Windows x86-64. Did I missed something?

Did you initialize the server and did you start the server? I'm not familiar with Windows, don't know how to check this, but there must some proces running that says "postgres"

@FrankHeikens, I'm not sure if I understood you exactly, however. When opening pgAdmin and the "PostgreSQL 16" server, a process appears in the task manager "postgres.exe" with the description of "PostgreSQL Server"

Forget pgAdmin for now, that's just a client and you can turn it off for now. You first have to initialize the PostgreSQL server. Did you initialize it or not? See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime.html

Advice: Get use to the psql client and other command line tools. These are your go-to tools when something doesn't work as expected. GUI tools like pgAdmin are a nice-to-have and for daily work, but not for fixing problems.

If your computer cannot display text in that locale, try changing your Windows locale to English. Then you should get a readable message.

Firstly, the exception transcription says (possibly): "Unable to connect to server: connection failed::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentification failed for user 'postgres'"
Given transctiption lost the after-username part of message, but it fits most from my point-of-view because fixing this error fixed my own error
Solution: use the account password that is mentioned in the "username" line. If it is "postgres" (a.k.a. superuser), use password for superuser account. If it's some "other account" (e.g. "anothername" on second picture), use the password from "other account"

Secondly, it possible to fix symbols encoding by changing machine language or using SQL Shell (psql). If the SQL Shell has broken encoding do next:

Open regedit
Go to \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
Create string parameter "Autorun"
Put in it value "chcp some digits" (in my case "chcp 1251")

That might possibly help with the SQL Shell encoding situation
